# Hard Disk Appear, Disappear and Reappear?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mount, centos-7, ext4

I just bought a brand new 8TB hard drive yesterday.

I connected it directly to my motherboard, and ran gdisk to re-partitioned and created ext4 (`mkfs.ext4`).

I saw it in my file manager, and I clicked it (which CentOS would mount for me after entering root's password).

Then, I didn't use it for like 30 mins or so.  It was unmounted somehow, and `fdisk -l` couldn't find it too, and file manager didn't see such drive too.

Then, I did nothing for another 10 mins or so, it reappeared in file manager, and `fdisk -l` found it again.  Then, I had to click it in file manager to remount again (renetering root's password).

Now, I wonder whether my HDD is bad.

I tried to run SMART's short test:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 2 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Sat Feb 16 09:47:11 2019
```

But the test seems not running:
What else can I check?

```
$ date
Sat 16 Feb 09:49:47 HKT 2019
$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
```

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick & easy fix is try a different data (SATA?) cable, maybe even power cable.

- Check the syslog (usually `/var/log/syslog` & `dmesg` for any messages about the drive when it disappears/reappears.

You might even be able to hear the drive working while testing / reading / writing, or even just spinning idle. So if it suddenly goes quiet while it should be working that's bad, especially if it disappears from all Linux tools / listings.

That's a little weird that the self test didn't log anything...

- You could try running the *short* self-test again, optionally in `-C`, `--captive` mode (some of my older drives would always abort the test ~90% if captive).
- While testing (not in captive mode) you could check the test's status with `smartctl -c /dev/sdX` to see "Self-test execution status:" and the next line has % remaining. Or just cut out those lines with:
  `smartctl -c /dev/sdX | grep "^Self" -A1`

  `-c` will also show what tests are supported.
- Try the other self tests (`conveyance`, `offline`, `long`)
- I like `smartctl --xall` to see all the results.

  - I believe the *"SMART Attributes Data Structure -> Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds"* has "problem" attributes showing a "VALUE" of 100 or less (higher numbers being better)
  - the "RAW_VALUES" are *very* vendor specific & might be a code & might not have any direct relation to the attribute (Power_On_Minutes & Power_Cycle_Count should be actual minutes & a count, but there may be no guarantees)
- Drives can put themselves to sleep after a while, but they should still remain connected & listed in Linux. There's a `smartctl` command to get & set it, here's the relevant section from the man page:

  > `-g NAME, --get=NAME, -s NAME[,VALUE], --set=NAME[,VALUE]`
  >
  > Gets/sets non-SMART device settings.  Note that the ´--set´ option shares its short
  >             option ´-s´ with ´--smart´.  Valid arguments are:
  >
  > `standby,[N|off]` - [ATA only] Sets the standby (spindown) timer and places the drive
  >             in the IDLE mode.  A value of 0 or ´off´ disables the standby timer.  Values from 1
  >             to 240 specify timeouts from 5 seconds to 20 minutes in 5 second increments.   Val‐
  >             ues  from  241  to 251 specify timeouts from 30 minutes to 330 minutes in 30 minute
  >             increments.  Value 252 specifies 21 minutes.  Value 253 specifies a vendor specific
  >             time  between 8 and 12 hours.  Value 255 specifies 21 minutes and 15 seconds.  Some
  >             drives may use a vendor specific interpretation for the values.  Note that there is
  >             no  get  option  because  ATA standards do not specify a method to read the standby
  >             timer.
- Is your power supply OK?

Comment: Thanks for all the detail steps.  The problem is my faulty SATA III cable.